# Codificação de String - Haskell

Tags: string, lista, programação-funcional, revisão-de-código, haskell

O seguinte código faz uma codificação sobre uma sequência de caracteres iguais, substituindo a sequência por !na, onde n é o número de vezes que o caractere a é repetido. Note que ele só comprime sequencias maiores que 3.

```
comprime :: String -> String
comprime "" = ""
comprime [c] = [c]
comprime (c:st) = let (seq,rest) = span (==c) (c:st)
                      len = length seq
                  in if len > 3 then ("!" ++ show len ++ [c]) ++ comprime rest
                     else seq++(comprime rest)
```

Visualizando:

```
ghci> comprime "asdffffghjjkllllpoooi"
"asd!4fghjjk!4lpoooi"
```

Minha dúvida é: Como eu conseguiria fazer o inverso? Por exemplo, trocar !4f por ffff? Eu não sei como pegar o caractere após o '!' e usá-lo como o número de vezes que o próximo caractere (no exemplo, 'f') se repete. Eu tentei usar o mesmo código mas n fez muito sentido pro compilador.

Answer (score 0):

esta função expande a compressão acima

`u ('!':n:c:oo)=replicate (read [n]) c ++ u oo
u (o:oo)=o:u oo`

exemplo (ghci):

`u "asd!4fghjjk!4lpoooi"
"asdffffghjjkllllpoooi`

é uma função recursiva e apenas funciona se o numero de replicações for inferior a 10, no entanto serve de inspiração para uma forma mais completa

se fosse de minha escolha eu usaria uma codificação inicial diferente, uma que não envolvesse o parse do inteiro